# Lithium: Run filter after find() to format output

Tags: php, lithium

I wanted to specify the output of a field from within my model so I added a `date` key to my `$_schema`:

`models/Tags.php`

```
<?php
    protected $_schema = array(
        'id'       => array('type' => 'integer', 'key'  => 'primary'),
        'title'    => array('type' => 'string'),
        'created'  => array('type' => 'integer', 'date' => 'F jS, Y - g:i a'),
        'modified' => array('type' => 'integer')
    );
?>
```

I store my time as an unsigned integer in the db (output of `time()`).

I want my base model to format any field that has the `date` key for output. I thought the best place to do that would be right after a `find`:

`extensions/data/Model.php`

```
<?php
    static::applyFilter('find', function($self, $params, $chain) {
        $schema = $self::schema();
        $entity = $chain->next($self, $params, $chain);

        foreach ($schema as $field => $options) {
            if (array_key_exists('date', $options)) {
                //format as a date
                $params['data'][$field] = $entity->formatDate($field, $options['date']);
            }
        }
        return $entity;
    });


    public function formatdate($entity, $field, $format, $timezone = 'Asia/Colombo') {
        $dt = new \DateTime();
        $tz = new \DateTimeZone($timezone);
        $dt->setTimestamp($entity->$field);
        $dt->setTimezone($tz);
        return $dt->format($format);
    }

?>
```

This doesn't seem to be working. When I execute a find all, this filter seems to get hit twice. The first time, `$entity` contains a `count()` of the results and only on the second hit does it contain the `Records` object.

What am I doing wrong? How do I alter this so that simply doing `<?= $tag->created; ?>` in my view will format the date the way I want? This, essentially, needs to be an 'after filter', of sorts.

**EDIT**

If I can find a way to access the current model entity object (not the full namespaced path, $self contains that), I can probably solve my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regardless of a small fix for your after find filter, I would do it differently.

Every time you'll do a find, you'll override your date format, even if you don't want to display it, but only do a business logic like comparing dates etc ...

Since you want to format your output **only in your views** (we are not talking about formatting on the fly json responses for an API, etc.), why not **using a helper method** ?

An other way is to add an instance method in your model (or a BaseModel), called `created_at()`. Then, you will call it from a view with `<?= $entity->created_at() ?>`
You can still force a format fetched from your $_schema, or pass it as a param, etc ...

A helper seems cleaner as we are talking about presenting data in your views.

Comment: I like this method better than using filters as well. You could also consider adding magic getters / setters to your entity like so: [https://gist.github.com/1946493](https://gist.github.com/1946493)

Comment: @Mehdi , The thing is, I know that for certain fields, I will always want a specific format because this is for a very specific application so using a filter makes more sense to me.

When I said 'views', I meant all forms of output.

I've always been using a helper but I don't like it as much for two reasons:
 1. it doesn't look neat
 2. most importantly, I don't want to give the designer room to make an error and type out `<?= $this->created; ?>` instead of `<?= $this->created(); ?>` when he's editing the templates.

Comment: @clexmond, I'm a little wary of using magic methods in Lithium as there's already so much magic going on in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading the OP's problem as the find filter executes twice. If that's right, then why not just check to see if the $entity contains a recordset?

Comment: I was actually using `is_a()` to check if the object was a `lithium\data\collection\RecordSet` object but that seemed inefficient and I was hoping for a better way. My biggest problem, however, is that I don't know how to assign the values to the Recordset object.

If I can find out how to access the model entity from within that filter, I could probably solve the problem.

Comment: @Housni I think the problem might be that you are accessing $params, which was what was passed in, instead of the params in the $entity that was returned from the $chain->next. Does that make sense?